# Incorporating phpBB 3.0 into our HTML page rather than in a whole page for itself?

Tags: php, html, forums

Having a bit of difficulty trying to incorporate the phpBB forum within a  on our own page.  Does anyone know if this is actually possible?

It might be that phpBB is not the correct product for the job but I had to start somewhere.  Looking for a low quantity Message Forum to incorporate into our website.  Rather than have it in it's own page I would like to build it into our standard page layout with our own Header, Menu, Quick links panel, floating Footer etc.

Can this be done, if so is phpBB the right Forum to use or should I be looking at something else.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't like saying this, but you can use an iframe, though I would discourage it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a phpBB board style which matches your regular page layout. See e.g. http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/how-to-create-a-style-basics/ for some details.

Note that phpBB updates can introduce changes to the default board style - when this happens, you will need to update your board style accordingly to make sure everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the phpBB template files (.tpl) to pull in your website framework and then the forum will be surrouned with your actual website e.g. header, menu, footer, etc.

Here's a little more info: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-518275.html